# D3 how to draw chart with a x data between two y data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I want to draw chart that can set x between two y for example I want to draw a chart with `x=100 and y1=200 , y2=500` just vertical line with good detail which chart can do that for me
something like this image
[image]

With specific x and y Which chart I should use to draw this

Comment: I don't think there's a specific ready-made chart for this, but doing it with D3 shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Seems like the easiest to modify would be some type of scatter/dot plot. This isn't really a question suited for SO, as it's rather broad/opinion-based.

Comment: You can do this in D3 by setting linear range/domains.

Comment: @Incodeveritas I am new to the d3 can you be more specific??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can see how to make Bar Chart using d3.js

[Bar chart using d3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)

Now the thing thing that you are trying to achieve is called floating Bar Chart.Although there is not any ready-made Floating bar chart available in d3. But we can achieve it by doing certain change in Bar chart itself.
When we are appending Rectangle in bar classes in the above example just change the height attribute to

```
 .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.higher-d.lower)
```

In this way it gives rectangle from the point lower to higher.
Json is in this format

```
var jsonData=[
 {"letter": "A", "higher": .08,"lower": .05},
 {"letter": "B", "higher": .05,"lower": .03},
 {"letter": "C", "higher": .04,"lower": .02}   
]
```

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8LV36/)

And for learning d3.js follow this [link](http://d3js.org/)